# how to utilize an overloaded pojo constructor with retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I would like to create a pojo that can hold both series one, and , when need be, series two. The data varies by year; 1975 has rain data, but 1976 has both rain AND snow data. In other words, I want my pojo to be able to hold rain data for years that have only rain data, and both rain/snow data for years that have rain/snow data.

```
{
    "status": "REQUEST_SUCCEEDED",
    "responseTime": 313,
    "message": [
        "No Data Available for Series 2 Year: 1975"
    ],
    "Results": {
        "series": [
            {
                "seriesID": "1",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M12",
                        "periodName": "December",
                        "value": "171.8",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M11",
                        "periodName": "November",
                        "value": "172.1",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M10",
                        "periodName": "October",
                        "value": "172.7",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M09",
                        "periodName": "September",
                        "value": "173.3",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M08",
                        "periodName": "August",
                        "value": "174.2",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M07",
                        "periodName": "July",
                        "value": "174.8",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M06",
                        "periodName": "June",
                        "value": "176.0",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M05",
                        "periodName": "May",
                        "value": "176.9",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M04",
                        "periodName": "April",
                        "value": "178.1",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M03",
                        "periodName": "March",
                        "value": "178.7",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M02",
                        "periodName": "February",
                        "value": "179.0",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M01",
                        "periodName": "January",
                        "value": "179.6",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1975",
                        "period": "M12",
                        "periodName": "December",
                        "value": "179.9",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1975",
                        "period": "M11",
                        "periodName": "November",
                        "value": "180.8",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1975",
                        "period": "M10",
                        "periodName": "October",
                        "value": "182.0",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1975",
                        "period": "M09",
                        "periodName": "September",
                        "value": "182.9",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1975",
                        "period": "M08",
                        "periodName": "August",
                        "value": "183.8",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1975",
                        "period": "M07",
                        "periodName": "July",
                        "value": "184.4",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1975",
                        "period": "M06",
                        "periodName": "June",
                        "value": "186.4",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1975",
                        "period": "M05",
                        "periodName": "May",
                        "value": "187.9",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1975",
                        "period": "M04",
                        "periodName": "April",
                        "value": "188.8",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1975",
                        "period": "M03",
                        "periodName": "March",
                        "value": "189.7",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1975",
                        "period": "M02",
                        "periodName": "February",
                        "value": "190.3",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1975",
                        "period": "M01",
                        "periodName": "January",
                        "value": "191.8",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "seriesID": "2",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M12",
                        "periodName": "December",
                        "value": "47.5",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M11",
                        "periodName": "November",
                        "value": "47.7",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M10",
                        "periodName": "October",
                        "value": "47.8",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M09",
                        "periodName": "September",
                        "value": "47.8",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M08",
                        "periodName": "August",
                        "value": "47.7",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M07",
                        "periodName": "July",
                        "value": "47.3",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M06",
                        "periodName": "June",
                        "value": "46.8",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M05",
                        "periodName": "May",
                        "value": "45.5",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M04",
                        "periodName": "April",
                        "value": "44.9",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M03",
                        "periodName": "March",
                        "value": "45.1",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M02",
                        "periodName": "February",
                        "value": "45.5",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "1976",
                        "period": "M01",
                        "periodName": "January",
                        "value": "45.9",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: create a pojo which contains both rain and snow data, and you can check that snow data is not null for a year,if it is not null that year contains snow and rain data both

Comment: I'm wondering how i would lead both snow and days onto a pojo since they're both labeled as "value"

Comment: that doesn't matter as value always has same datatype and by checking the year you can check that it is snow data or rain data

Comment: Can you give me a code example?

Comment: If you have to differentiate between rain and snow data then you will have to have two different parameters, e.g: rainValue and snowValue

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a POJO for an object in data array

```
public class WeatherData
{
public String year;
public String period;
public String periodName;
public String Value;
List<Footnotes> footnotes;
}
```

you can create getter and setter by your own i do not know about footnotes as it is always empty so you can change is according to your will,you can check that it is rain data or snow data by checking the session seriesID because by seeing your JSON i think seriesID 1 contains rain data and seriesID 2 contains snow data,but i would suggest as @frek13 also mentioned it would be better if you can have two variables one for rain data and one for snow data

Comment: How would I set retrofit to do that? I already used jsonschema2pojo. I got Results, Series, and Datum as my models; I got rid of footnote because i don't really ever see where it's used. How do I set up my datum so that it'll take in a rain AND snow variable?

Comment: Create a callback with the POJO you have created and the callback will store your response